# How can we use TypeScript mixins with dependency injection?

Tags: angular, typescript, mixins

When I use mixins for multiple inheritance, if in any of the classes from which I inherit I have dependency injection, how can I use super ()?

Example of code:

Mixin:

```
export const applyMixins = (derivedCtor: any, baseCtors: any[]) => {
  baseCtors.forEach(baseCtor => {
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(baseCtor.prototype).forEach(name => {
      Object.defineProperty(derivedCtor.prototype, name, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(baseCtor.prototype, name));
    });
  });
};
```

AsyncComponent constructor:

```
export class AsyncComponent {
  constructor(private communication: CommunicationsService) {}
}
```

Interface:

```
export interface DashboardPageComponent extends AsyncComponent {}
```

Constructor:

```
export class DashboardPageComponent {

constructor(private myPropertiesService: MyPropertiesService, private state: StateService) {
    super()
  }
}
```

I get the following error:

> 'super' can only be referenced in a derived class

On the other hand, how do I use super() if I inherit several classes with dependency injection?

Comment: You should check out the mixins introduced in TypeScript 2.2 ([see here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-2.html)). They're much better than what the TypeScript handbook recommends for mixins.

Comment: Thanks  @DavidSherret , I'm going to take a look at that documentation